# Is this a memory leak? Trying to reset class members of type class. C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
class Levels{
     public:
               Levels();
               Player* one;
               Player* two;
               Player* three;
               Player* four;
               void reset();
}

Levels::Levels()
{
     one = new Player(...);
     two= new Player(...);
     three= new Player(...);
     four= new Player(...);
}

void Levels::reset()
{
     delete one;
     delete two;
     delete three;
     delete four;
     one = new Player(...);
     two= new Player(...);
     three= new Player(...);
     four= new Player(...);
}
```

basically in reset it deletes the old players and makes them all new again. It works but i don't know if it is okay to do.

Comment: Is it C++? Add the language tag.

Comment: @Yu_Hao yes it is C++

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't leak memory. But what happens if Levels is copied? That will leak without copy constructor etc. Does it have destructor?

Why not use a smart pointer, such as `std::unique_ptr<Player>`. This will automatically delete old players when reset or destroyed.

Comment: I've heard of smart pointers, but i've never used them. Should i use them on every single pointer? Or is that stupid? Are they only for C++11?

Comment: You don't have to use them on every pointer, but it is better to have too many than not enough. C++11 standardises two useful smart pointers (unique_ptr and shared_ptr). Before that, it depends on your compiler if they are included, or you need a library. (It only has auto_ptr which is not as useful).

Comment: @fuzymarshmello You should use them for all owning pointers (pointer responsible for destroying the pointee) or use RAII in general to do it cleanly and easily. Look at the RAII wikipedia page and other documentations related.